# Collation sequence in Google Script different from Google Sheets--What to do?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

My problem is with the 'Ł' character. In Google Sheets 'Łukasiewicz' comes before 'Martin'. But in Google Apps Script 'Łukasiewicz' comes after 'Martin', i.e., ( "Łukasiewicz" > "Martin" ) is true. I need to have Google Apps Script behave the same as Google Sheets. Any advice?

Comment: In order to replicate and correctly understand your situation, can you provide a sample script and sample Spreadsheet? I think that it will help users think of about your issue.

Comment: You'll need to write your own sort. Note that the basic `<` sort considers the string character by character, and the ASCII letters come much before any Unicode does.